# Count the number of frequency for different characters in a string

Tags: c#-4.0

i am currently tried to create a small program were the user enter a string in a text area, clicks on a button and the program counts the frequency of different characters in the string and shows the result on another text area.
E.g. Step 1:- User enter:- aaabbbbbbcccdd
     Step 2:- User click the button
     Step 3:- a 3
              b 6
              c 3
              d 1
This is what I've done so far....

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        string s = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            s = textBox1.Text;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++ )
            {
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(s[i]);
                if (dic.Equals(s[i]))
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    dic.Add(Convert.ToString(s[i]), count++);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas or help how can I countinue because till now the program is giving a run time error when there are same charachter!!

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to compare the entire dictionary to a string, that doesn't tell you if there is a key in the dictionary that corresponds to the string. As the dictionary never is equal to the string, your code will always think that it should add a new item even if one already exists, and that is the cause of the runtime error.

Use the `ContainsKey` method to check if the string exists as a key in the dictionary.

Instead of using a variable `count`, you would want to increase the numbers in the dictionary, and initialise new items with a count of one:

```
string key = s[i].ToString();
textBox2.Text = key;
if (dic.ContainsKey(key)) {
  dic[key]++;
} else {
  dic.Add(key, 1);
}
```

Comment: I tried the above however compiler is giving error that I have invalid arguments... I guess the problem is because dic takes two arguments a string and int....

Comment: @user2307236: Yes, you are right. The value has to be a string everywhere it's used with the dictionary. I updated the code above.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lettersAndCounts = s.GroupBy(c=>c).Select(group => new { 
                             Letter= group.Key, 
                             Count = group.Count() 
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `dic.Equals` use `dic.ContainsKey`. However, i would use this little linq query:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = textBox1.Text
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.ToString(), g => g.Count());
```

Comment: I've used the linq query and it is working fine... since I am a beginner can you kindly explain what is happening in the few lines of code.. Tks

Comment: @user2307236: It's even only a single line. [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) groups each char in the string by it's value, `ToDictionary` creates a dictionary by a provided key and a value. The key is the `Key` property of the group which is the char. If you use `GroupBy` is it ensured that you get no duplicates. The value is the `IEnumerable<Char>` of same chars. The `Enumerable.Count` method enumerates these chars to get the total count of each group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a different and somewhat simpler approach for doing this. Assuming you are using English strings, you can create an array with capacity = 26. Then depending on the character you encounter you would increment the appropriate index in the array. For example, if the character is 'a' increment count at index 0, if the character is 'b' increment the count at index 1, etc...

Your implementation will look something like this:

```
int count[] = new int [26] {0};

for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
{
   count[Char.ToLower(s[i]) - int('a')]++;
}
```

When this finishes you will have the number of 'a's in count[0] and the number of 'z's in count[25].

Comment: I cannot understand this part of code ..... - int('a')]++ and also {0} can you kindly explain....

Comment: The {0} initializes all the elements in your count array to 0.
int('a') basically returns the ascii code for the character a which is actually 97. So if you encounter 'b' we will increment index 98-97=1! 98 here is the ascii of 'b' and so on. Letter z has ascii 122 and will be placed in index 122-97=25.