# simple solution for characters frequency in string object

Tags: c#, character, frequency

The task what I'm trying to do is about showing up the frequency of every single characters from the string object, for the moment I've done some part of code, just doesn't have the easy concept in my mind for finishing this task. So far I was thinking that it might be usefull to changing the char into int type. What is worth mentioning I'd like to avoid using the part: if (letter == 'a') NumberCount++; as if it wouldnt be efficient to write that much conditions for that simple task, and I'was thinking of doing it way mentioned above. I'd be gratefull for any sugestions of how to code it further.....I'm beginner at c#

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string sign = "attitude";
       for (int i = 0; i < sign.Length; i++)
       {
          int number = sign[i]; // changing char into int

       }
```

Comment: You're looking to see how many times each character shows up in a string? So for example, for your "attitude" example, you would have:
`a - 1
t - 3
i - 1
u - 1
d - 1
e - 1
` ?

Comment: I don't understand how you would avoid `if(letter=='a')` if you want to count  how many times the letter a shows up?  And how would the `int` value of the characters have anything to do with counting them?

Comment: I was thinking of the ASCI of the single characters, that might be usefull

Comment: @NicholasEllingson that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: you need to think and by that .. please relay to us what you are trying to do..are you trying to determine how many times each letter shows up? if so then state that.. this is not that difficult either @Arturs sounds like your're looking more for someone to provide you the answer.. you can google this for examples very easily googles works for me all the time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181117/count-the-number-of-frequency-for-different-characters-in-a-string

Comment: Well the language barieer seemed to be getting quite disturbing sooner or later...... it's just what You've just told : )

Comment: the user dont want to put 26 condition for all the letters @juharr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a non Linq way to get the counts of all the unique letters.

```
var characterCount= new Dictionary<char,int>();
foreach(var c in sign)
{
    if(characterCount.ContainsKey(c))
        characterCount[c]++;
    else
        characterCount[c] = 1;
}
```

Then to find out how many "a"s there are

```
int aCount = 0;
characterCount.TryGetValue('a', out aCount);
```

Or to get all the counts

```
foreach(var pair in characterCount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: he wants a count for all letters so I think it would be `a=1 t=3..etc...`

Comment: @MethodMan I'm not sure I completely follow, but I've updated to show how to get all the unique character counts by iterating over the dictionary.

Comment: `plus 1"` for the update and answer @ArturS was not clear initially

Comment: I'd like to thank all of You for Your's support : )) I'll surely analyze your's recommendals : ))

Answer (score 7):

You can easily do it using Linq like:

```
 string sign = "attitude";
 int count = sign.Count(x=> x== 'a');
```

or if you want all characters count then:

```
 string sign = "attitude";
 var alphabetsCount = sign.GroupBy(x=> x)
                          .Select(x=>new 
                                    {
                                      Character = x.Key, 
                                      Count = x.Count()
                                    });
```

[Here is a working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4miPAM)

### UPDATE:

Without Linq you can do it with a loop and track it in a dictionary like:

```
string sign = "attitude";
Dictionary<char,int> dic = new Dictionary<char,int>();
foreach(var alphabet in sign)
{
    if(dic.ContainsKey(alphabet))
        dic[alphabet] = dic[alphabet] +1;
    else
        dic.Add(alphabet,1);
}
```

[Here is Demo without Linq using Dictionary<>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JFpIsC)

Comment: Is there a way doing it without using built in c# functions : ) ?

Comment: @ArturS Do you mean not using Linq?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean

Comment: then you have to for loop and use a dictionary for it

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do it without Linq, then try

```
var charDictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
string sign = "attitude";
foreach(char currentChar in sign)
{
    if(charDictionary.ContainsKey(currentChar))
    { charDictionary[currentChar]++; }
    else
    { charDictionary.Add(currentChar, 1); }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `ToCharArray` since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: I've never realized that before, thanks. That would make things go faster as well because then there wouldn't be the conversion to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            char ch;
            Console.Write("Enter a string:");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            for (ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
            {
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ch==str[i] || str[i] == (ch + 32))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Char {0} having Freq of {1}", ch, count);
                }
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Others have also posted the Linq way, but I found a slightly shorter to do it with just a for loop using **GetValueOrDefault**.

```
string sign = "attitude";
foreach(var c in sign){
    counts[c] =  counts.GetValueOrDefault(c) + 1;
}
```

`GetValueOrDefault(char key)` returns 0 (the default value for an `int`) when the key for the letter doesn't exist in the dictionary yet and returns the current count once it exists so we just add 1 to it each time we see the same letter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the simplest solution is by using Linq:

```
var charFreqMap = sign.GroupBy(ch => ch).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```