# how to have a list of 'a' to 'z'?

Tags: c#

I have a code that I want to count the number of appearing each letter in alphabet in the input string.
I used a dictionary<char, int> to have a key for each letter and a value as the count of appearance.
So, how to have a list of 'a' to 'z' to use as keys?
I've tried this:

```
Dictionary<char, int> alphabetCounter = new Dictionary<char, int>();
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
    alphabetCounter[ch] = 0;
```

Is it a better way to have the list of 'a' to 'z'?
Thank you.

Comment: If this wasn't asking for a "better" way (better how?), it would be a duplicate of [Generating an array of letters in the alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/314466/215552)

Comment: Totally opinion based as @HereticMonkey said... If you are looking for the most compact way - `var alphabetCounter = "abc".ToDictionary(keySelector: x=>x, x=>0);` is probably shortest one... also indeed that's pointless as you get result directly anyway with `GroupBy` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31863230/477420

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Linq` try this to have a list from "a" to "z".

```cs
var list = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(c => (char)c).ToList();
```

If you want to get in upper case, is the same but using upper case.

```cs
var list = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(c => (char)c).ToList();
```

Edit:

Your question is to get the list, but to get as dictionary you can use `.ToDictionary()` and initialize with value 0:

```cs
var dictionary = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(c => (char)c).ToDictionary(i => (char)i, i => 0);
```

The same case to upper/lower case.

Comment: Thank you man. your answer was the best.

Comment: I appreciate if you explain this part ('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1) of your code for me @J.F.

Comment: 'A' and 'Z' are `char` values and [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-5.0) expects integer, so `char` is parsed to `int`. The `int` value is the ASCII code, so the `Enumerable.Range()` con loop through the letters from 'A' to the end, calculated with 'Z' - 'A' +1. If you prefer I edit the question and I try to explain better.

Comment: That's really kind of you @J.F.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it in LINQ:

```cs
var alphabetCounter = Enumerable.Range(97, 26).ToDictionary(i => (char)i, i => 0);
```

This will create a dictionary with all chars with values 0.

ASCII codes of alphabet (lowercase) begins at 97, we can then take 26 numbers from there and convert them to `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Is performance a thing? You can keep it simple.
You do not need to create your own dictionary, register every possibility then start `counter[i]++` for each ocurrence, seems a bit of an overkill to me.

You can group up the letters by using `.GroupBy` (System.Linq), then after you can check the count of each ocurrence.

Example:

```
var word = "test";
var groupedLetters = word.GroupBy(x => x);

foreach(var letter in groupedLetters)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{letter.Key} - {letter.Count()}");
}
```

Output:

```
t - 2  
e - 1  
s - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi May this example will help :**

```
List<char> LS = new List<char>() {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'A'};
Dictionary<char,int> AlphaDictionary = (from x in LS group x by x).Select(x => new {Alpha = x.Key, Count = x.Count()}).ToDictionary(x=>x.Alpha,x=>x.Count);
```