# User input array and display frequency of each integer

Tags: c#

This is the problem given:
Write a program in C# that prompts the user to enter a number of integer values. The program
stores the integers in an array, counts the frequency of each integer and displays the frequency on the Console.

I am new to C# and don`t know Linq or dictionary yet.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    //declare variables
    int n,
    y,
    x;
    int[] index;
    int[] count;

    //prompt user for the number of elements
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of element to be stored");
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    index = new int[n];
    count = new int[n];
    //Console.WriteLine(index.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("input {0} number of element", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++) {

        index[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (y = 0; y < index.Length; y++)

        if (index[y] == i) count[i]++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < index.Length; j++)

    Console.WriteLine("element - {0} : {1}", j, index[j]);

    Console.WriteLine("the frequency of all elements of the array");
    for (x = 0; x < index.Length; x++)

    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurs {1} times", index[x], x);
}
```

This the result I get if I select 3 integers of 2, 1, 2. 2 is repeated.

```
    2 occurs 0 times.
    1 occurs 1 times.
    2 occurs 2 times.
```

Comment: you can try *Linq*: `string frequencyReport = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, index.GroupBy(item => item).Select(group => $"{group.Key} occurs {group.Count()} times."));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simple solution for characters frequency in string object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863204/simple-solution-for-characters-frequency-in-string-object)

Answer (score 0):

You’re doing in wring way. And perform wise also it’s not efficient solution. You are run for loop inside for loop. You can use dictionary and store the count in it, so it will work in a single for loop.

```
static void GetFrequency(int[] arr)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> mp = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    // Traverse through array elements and count frequencies             
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (mp.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
        {
            var val = mp[arr[i]];

            mp.Remove(arr[i]);
            mp.Add(arr[i], val + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            mp.Add(arr[i], 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `mp.Remove(arr[i]);mp.Add(arr[i], val + 1);`, you can simply increment the value.

Comment: @DragandDrop yes, I agree. Will modify

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when we want to *query* (i.e. find out frequencies) a collection (array) we use *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  var freqData = index
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(group => $"{group.Key} occurs {group.Count()} times.");

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, freqData));
```

If you want to count frequency *manually*, you can use `Dictionary<int, int>` to have `Key` (item from the array)
and `Value` (frequency) correspondence:

```
  Dictionary<int, int> freqData = new Dictionary<int, int>();

  foreach (int item in index)
    if (freqData.TryGetValue(item, out int freq))
      freqData[item] = freq + 1;
    else
      freqData.Add(item, 1);

  foreach (var pair in freqData)
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} occurs {pair.Value} times.");
```